# How to get ip address by session in Joomla using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla, joomla3.4

Is there any way that I could get the session's ip address in my Joomla website using sql?

As I can see in the session table I only have session_id, client_id, guest, time, data, userid, username.

Is there anyway that I could extract also the IP address of user that has an open session on my website?

Please note that i cannot use `JFactory::getSession()->get(...)` or any other PHP code. I can only access my server's sql database.

Comment: How come you can't run PHP code? Do you not have access to the files?

Comment: @johnny_s no, i dont have direct access. You see i am connecting to the database using a java web applications and i am generating reports... so i cant run php code...

Comment: So you are you expecting to get a user IP? Using Java? You can't use MySQL as user IP's are not stored in the database by default

Comment: Is there any extension that i could use that stores the sessions ips in the db?

Answer (score 1):

You could set a custom session variable in Joomla like so:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('ip', $ip);
```

**Update:**

Use the following to get the IP instead of `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/15989/168

Comment: Could this be implemented with [Sourcerer](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer)  @Lodder?

Comment: @johnny_s - Yes, but If this is required for every page, I would suggest adding it using Sourcerer to a custom HTML module then set that module to the `debug` position and to all menu items.

Comment: i dont want to display this info in this website... i want to extract the info to another website using sql..... Please see my question

Comment: As mentioned in my comment, you can use SQL because the IP of a user is **not** stored in the database by default. If you can't use PHP at all, then please update the tags in your question